# Android : How to terminate activity using if block

Tags: android

In my Android application I need to validate user entered data. So I have used if block to do that. If user entered data is invalid I want to stop running the activity further. How to do this within if block I tried to use `System.exit(0)` but it didn't work for me.
I don't know whether there is proper way to do this without using if statements please help me.

E.g.:

```
if(!uName.equals("User")) {
    // Here I want to terminate the activity
}
```

Comment: if(!uName.equals("User")){
    finish();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call `finish()`.

```
if ( !uName.equals( "User" ) ){
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `finish()` method of activity to finish current activity...